# Workaround to avoid "Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'Derived_N' and 'Base'" error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some types hierarchy:

```
public class Base {}
public class Derived_1 : Base {}
public class Derived_2 : Base {}
// more descendants...
public class Derived_N : Base {}
```

Types from this hierarchy are used as lookup lists in view models:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    // available items
    public IEnumerable<Derived_N> SomeItems { get; }

    // currently selected item
    public Derived_N SelectedItem { get; set; }

    // there could be several property pairs as above
}
```

To select values from lookup list I've created user control (some sort of selector). Since from the point of selection process all `Base` descendants looks similar, user control operates `Base` type properties:

```
    public IEnumerable<Base> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Base>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<Base>), typeof(BaseSelector), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Base SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (Base)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(Base), typeof(BaseSelector), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

XAML usually looks like:

```
<myCtrls:BaseSelector ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

This works as expected, but there are binding errors like this:

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions
>   between types 'Derived_N' and 'Base'

I know, *why* they are in output window - in theory, `SelectedItem` could be any type, derived from `Base`, but in practice this is not my case.
The error disappears, if this converter:

```
public class DummyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

is used in binding:

```
<myCtrls:BaseSelector ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource DummyConverterKey}}"/>
```

but I don't want to use it at all - as you can see, there are no any payload in that converter (while there are lot such of properties).

Are there any other workaround?

Comment: Can't you use UIPropertyMetadata?

Comment: @KyloRen: yes, sure.

Comment: then that's your solution. with UIPropertyMetadata you'll not get the waring. should I post this as answer?

Comment: @KyloRen: oops, sorry. I've looked at `UIPropertyMetadata` more attentively - I really need `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`, to set this manually in each binding will be a pain.

Comment: have u seen the binding at run time. I've created a example with UIPropertyMetadata  and it was working as two way by default. (for my dependency property)

Comment: @KyloRen: it worked as one way (and, AFAIK, this is default mode), that's why I've added `BindsTwoWayByDefault` option.

Comment: k. I wonder how it works with the properties in existing framework.

Comment: hey, I just used the type converter to avoid this error. Check this works for you. My code kind of messy(may be some deviated) but you should be able to see the relative info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, I've solved a problem with replacing property type for user control's properties to `IEnumerable` / `object` respectively (`IEnumerable<object>` / `object` is also a solution):

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(BaseSelector), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(BaseSelector), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

This leads to extra type checking inside user control, but doesn't generate any binding errors (and I really don't understand, why - the case with `object` is the same as with `Base`, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

use **TypeConverter** with your classes to avoid this error:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public class Derived_N : Base
{
}
```

**TypeConverter:**

```
public class MyConverter: TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
    Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(Base);
    }

public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return value as Base;
    }

public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
    Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(Base);
    }

public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return value == null ? null : value as Base;
    }
}
```

**PS:** please change the above code as your need. I just wrote the minimal to prevent error.